# Using Neural Net weights derived in Matlab on other programming language

Tags: python, matlab, pattern-matching, neural-network

I'm having trouble replicating a neural net created in matlab using python. Its a `{9,8,4}` network. Below is the original output in matlab and python respectively

```
0.00187283763854096 0.00280257304094145 0.00709416898379967 0.00474275971385824 0.000545071722266366
0.0520122170317888  0.0402746073491970  0.0179208146529717  0.0245726107168336  0.230693355244371
0.430695009441386   0.434492291029203   0.410151021812136   0.416871471927059   0.469873849186641
0.562954025662924   0.539410486293765   0.666336481449288   0.637779009735872   0.284564488176231

[1.0, -1.0, -0.6875955603907775, -0.9999999426232321]
[1.0, -1.0, 0.5569364789701737, -0.9994593106654553]
[1.0, -1.0, 0.5022468075847347, -0.999780120038859]
[1.0, -1.0, 0.4924691499951816, -0.9997110849203137]
[1.0, -1.0, 0.5945295051094253, -0.9991584098381949]
```

I obtained the input and layered weights using `net2.IW{1}`, `net2.LW{2}`. The bias was obtained as follows; `net2.b{1}` and `net2.b{2}`.

Without using bias, I got something that looks close:

```
[-0.6296705512038354, 0.9890465283687858, 0.1368924025968622, 0.5426776395855755]
[-0.05171165478856995, 0.2973298654798701, 0.02897695903082293, 0.0499820714219222]
[-0.10046933055782481, 0.40531232885083035, 0.033067381241777244, 0.06585830703439044]
[0.03167268710874907, 0.5485036035542894, 0.10579223668518502, 0.015475934153332364]
[0.006502829360007152, 0.22928662468119648, 0.03788967208701787, 0.012868192806301859]
```

Hence I think the problem may lie in the bias; I'm not quite sure though.

Python implementation with weights taken from Matlab

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return math.tanh(x)

def NN(inputs, bias1, bias2):
    wsum=[sum([(x*y) for x,y in zip(inputs[0],row)])for row in inputweights]
    wsbias=[(x + y) for x,y in zip(wsum,bias1)]
    inputactivation=[sigmoid(k) for k in wsbias]
    wsoutput=[sum([(x*y) for x,y in zip(inputactivtion,row)])for row in     hiddenweights]
    wsbias2=[(x + y) for x,y in zip(wsoutput,bias2)]
    outputactivation=[sigmoid(k) for k in wsbias2] 
    return 'output' outputactivation
```

I would really appreciate any solution that works.
Below are input and Layered weights as well as input and layered bias obtained.

```
IW=[[-9.1964,   -2.3015,    0.2493,    3.3648,   -2.6015,   -0.0795,  -11.2356,    4.6861,-0.8360],
    [6.0201,   -1.8708,    2.7844,    0.2419,   -1.1808,   -8.6800,    5.8519,   -5.2958,    5.3233],
    [0.8597,    0.8644,   -0.6913,   -0.0397,    0.0619,    0.4506,    1.0687,    0.4090,   -0.2874],
    [2.9459,    3.2596,    2.2859,    1.1933,    2.9675,   -9.6017,    3.5893,    1.4808,   -7.5311],
   [-0.1533,   -1.4806,   -2.3748,    0.8059,   -0.5502,   -1.0447,   -0.5920,   -1.1667,   -1.1447],
    [4.7185,   -9.2097,    1.1001,   -0.0173,    1.4929,    0.3884,    3.7674,    6.3459,   -4.2845],
  [-16.4031,    8.1351,    2.0689,    2.1267,    6.2093,   -8.3875,  -15.8493,   -0.6096,    2.9214],
    [1.7329,    0.1797,   0.1500,    9.1616,   -1.7226,    0.9479,    3.2542,  -24.4003,   -4.2790]]

LW=[[-18.5985,   12.2366,  -0.8833,   -1.6382,    4.6281,    8.1221,  -23.7587,   -0.8589],
   [12.0462,  -11.5464,    6.9612,  -10.8562,   -7.0647,    5.6653,   16.2527,   -7.6119],
   [12.4176,    0.9808,    0.7650,  -2.9434,   -0.2765,   -3.0689,   -3.1528,   3.0389],
    [5.7570,   7.7584,  -6.9550,   -2.3679,   -1.4884,  -11.0668,    2.6764,   26.5427]]

bias1=[-1.7639, -1.2599, -0.7560, 0.2520,-0.2520,0.7560, -1.2599, -1.7639]
bias2= [0.2129,-8.1812, 0.0202,4.4512]
```

My inputs

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0414444125526, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00670501464516, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0313140652051], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.00398243636152, 0.0, 0.0, 0.000863557858377, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00356406423776], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.00440892765754, 0.0, 0.0, 0.000725737283104, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00543503005753], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.00565322288091, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00236630383341, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00642911490856], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.00250332223564, 0.0, 0.0, 0.000926998841251, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00241792804103], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Bias is sometimes added as a first or last column in the weights matrix, sometimes as its own vector. This is not language-dependent though, it is library-dependent. Can you give the library names? Also some code for how you create the network/weights in Python (showing where you have used the values you extracted earlier.

Comment: Also, are you sure you are using same transfer/activation function?

Comment: @Neil Slater, thanks for responding.  I used nprtool, and tansig transfor function.

Comment: @NeilSlater, I have included my implementation in python using the weights and bias derived from matlab.

Comment: Is your bias in inputs?

Comment: @runDOSrun, no, I didn't include my bias in the input. After the weight_sum, I then add bias to each node before using the activation function.

Comment: @NeilSlater, I have updated the posing with the weights and bias I obtained form matlab. I have also corrected the code.

Comment: Ah, and also the inputs for case 1 (where Matlab output `[0.00187283763854096 0.00280257304094145 0.00709416898379967 0.00474275971385824 0.00054507172226636]` - oh, wait that's *5* outputs from a 4-output network, have you transposed them, it's not clear?

Comment: This may be relevant: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/14517-processing-of-i-p-data

Comment: @NeilSlater, its correct. `0.00187283763854096  
0.0520122170317888    
0.430695009441386      
0.562954025662924'

Comment: OK, so example 1 is: `[0.00187283763854096, 0.0520122170317888, 0.430695009441386, 0.562954025662924]` . . . and Python gave you `[1.0, -1.0, -0.6875955603907775, -0.9999999426232321]`? The fact that you have no negative values in the Matlab output makes me think output layer is *not* tansig as you have implemented it, although even allowing for that, something else is not matching

Comment: @NeilSlater, I have now included input, hence you have the complete information. You can now try to implement with tansig.

Comment: I cannot figure it out, sorry. I think you need someone who knows nprtool in more detail - it is likely you need to extract more than just the weights and biases in order to fully copy the network behaviour to Python.